# Prestashop problems with add to cart a product

Tags: prestashop

I am using PS 1.6.

My issue is with adding the same product to cart after already added before. So, let's say for first time I add:

product X > I select qty 4 items > press add to cart
- AJAX pop up windows appears. I see that 4 Items are added to cart

And then, I decide to add few more qty's of the same product X. So, I select 3 more and add to cart, but the problem is that now instead of 3 items it adds just 1

so what can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Could you look into the dev tools console (right click anywhere, choose developer tools) and post here whatever (red) error messages you see?

Comment: Unfortunately it is empty in console tool

Comment: maybe you could provide your site link so we can have a look